# Remove Image from the JButton

Tags: java, swing

I am working on the Tic Tac application all things are set but the only problem is that I am using images on the Button and I want to make a restart button when this restart Button pressed I want that all the images on the Button should be removed. I have also tried to `setIcon(null)` but when the Restart button press image is removed and one another problem arises is that Button's get disabled and I am not able to play again.

Is there is any other methods available to remove the icon from the Button?

Answer (score 3):

The *OP* issue is more than `setIcon(null)`, so I am giving this reply,

Try below source code, but there is a good multi pane scenario for you:

[image: AddAndRemoveMultiPaneImages]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/*
 * Used resources within this class or illustration done within is just for the
 * study purpose.
 */
public class ImageExample extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
     * used fixed images resource, you can take all directory resources as per your
     * need
     */
    private String[] leopard = new String[] { "leopard0", "leopard1", "leopard2", "leopard3" };
    private URL url;
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4;
    private ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ImageExample() {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ImageExample();
            }
        });
    }

    private void init() {
        setTitle("Add And Remove Image");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBounds(400, 150, 625, 400);

        for (int i = 0; i < leopard.length; i++)
            index.add(i);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // 1
        panel.add(label1 = new JLabel(getIndexIcon(index.get(0))));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        add(panel, c);

        panel = new JPanel(); // 2
        panel.add(label2 = new JLabel(getIndexIcon(index.get(1))));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        add(panel, c);

        panel = new JPanel(); // 3
        panel.add(label3 = new JLabel(getIndexIcon(index.get(2))));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        add(panel, c);

        panel = new JPanel(); // 4
        panel.add(label4 = new JLabel(getIndexIcon(index.get(3))));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        add(panel, c);

        panel = new JPanel(); // contains JButtons
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(panel, c);

        final JButton prev = new JButton("Previous");
        final JButton addImage = new JButton("Add Image");
        final JButton removeImage = new JButton("Remove Image");
        final JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        addImage.setEnabled(false);

        panel.add(prev);
        panel.add(addImage);
        panel.add(removeImage);
        panel.add(next);

        prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                revalidateLabel(label1, revalidateIndex(0, index.get(0) - 1));
                revalidateLabel(label2, revalidateIndex(1, index.get(1) - 1));
                revalidateLabel(label3, revalidateIndex(2, index.get(2) - 1));
                revalidateLabel(label4, revalidateIndex(3, index.get(3) - 1));
            }
        });

        addImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                revalidateLabel(label1, index.get(0));
                revalidateLabel(label2, index.get(1));
                revalidateLabel(label3, index.get(2));
                revalidateLabel(label4, index.get(3));

                addImage.setEnabled(false);
                removeImage.setEnabled(true);
                prev.setEnabled(true);
                next.setEnabled(true);
                removeImage.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        removeImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                removeLabelImage(label1);
                removeLabelImage(label2);
                removeLabelImage(label3);
                removeLabelImage(label4);

                prev.setEnabled(false);
                next.setEnabled(false);
                removeImage.setEnabled(false);
                addImage.setEnabled(true);
                addImage.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                revalidateLabel(label1, revalidateIndex(0, index.get(0) + 1));
                revalidateLabel(label2, revalidateIndex(1, index.get(1) + 1));
                revalidateLabel(label3, revalidateIndex(2, index.get(2) + 1));
                revalidateLabel(label4, revalidateIndex(3, index.get(3) + 1));
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private ImageIcon getIndexIcon(int indexAt) {
        if (indexAt < 0)
            indexAt = leopard.length - 1;

        if (indexAt > (leopard.length - 1))
            indexAt = 0;

        url = ImageExample.class.getResource("/resources/leopard" + indexAt + ".jpg");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url.getPath());
        return icon;
    }

    private void revalidateLabel(JLabel label, int indexAt) {
        label.setIcon(getIndexIcon(indexAt));
        label.revalidate();
    }

    private void removeLabelImage(JLabel label) {
        label.setIcon(null);
        label.revalidate();
    }

    private int revalidateIndex(int indexAt, int indx) {
        if (indx < 0)
            indx = leopard.length - 1;

        if (indx > (leopard.length - 1))
            indx = 0;

        index.set(indexAt, indx);
        return indx;
    }

}
```

Comment: one more thing is that as i am using the image on the JButton so i want that a image that is set on on the JButton should not be changed i have tried setEnabled(false) but the JButton bomcomes dull in color

Comment: @lovesoni Okay, if this helps you, lets took a look on #Alex Lockwood on [how to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer), because it takes time to reply you and on different issue, you are free to ask separate question.